# Copy a function on the fly PHP

Tags: php, variables, copy, instance, on-the-fly

I'm working on a project which requires a function to be copied & executed on the fly and variables in it needs to be replaced on the fly too.

A simple example will be like this:

```
function myfunction()
{
    $abc = $_SESSION['abc'];
    return $abc;
}
```

I want to be able to call myfunction1() which does NOT physically exist in the code but does exactly the samething as the one above except it now take values from my custom variable so it'll look like this:

```
 function myfunction1()
 {
     $abc = $myCustomVariable;
     return $abc;
 }
```

Any one help pls?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  I bet you there's a better solution.

Comment: Have you considered using a parameter?

Comment: Because in fact that function is a massive one which does lots of different things that i don't want to duplicate it in my code & i don't want to mess with the SESSION as well. Thanks

Comment: Parameter is not an option because the function does lots of stuff with SESSIONs in side it. I really want to pull data from database, make it the same structure to fake the SESSIONs.

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate it?  Consider refactoring your function so that you **don't** need to duplicate it.  The solution to your example is just to pass the variable as an argument.  If that isn't sufficient, please update your question to include a realistic example.

Comment: I think you must use the OOP and do not try to do such dumb things.

Comment: Thanks, my code is fully OOP'ed though :) Just tried to think of a quick solution if there was one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more you describe how convoluted your function is, the more it sounds like a perfect candidate for an object with injected dependencies.

For instance, you could have (just going to describe the basic interfaces here):

```
class myClass
{
    public function __construct($provider DataProvider)
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    // Please name this something better
    public function doStufferer()
    {
        if ($this->provider->hasParam('foo'))
        {
            return $this->provider->getParam('foo');
        }
    }
}

class SessionProvider implements DataProvider
{
    // Session specific stuff
}

class OtherProvider implements DataProvider
{
    // Other provider stuff
}

interface DataProvider
{
    public function getParam($key);
    public function hasParam($key);
    public function setParam($key, $value);
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
$dataProcessor = new myClass(new SessionProvider);
// OR $dataProcessor = new myClass(new OtherProvider);
$dataProcessor->doStufferer();
```

Please take a look at [**PHP Classes and Objects**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and the other related topics.

Answer (score 1):

This is what parameters are for, I think your looking todo something like this:

```
$myCustomVariable = 'Some value';


function myfunction($var=$_SESSION['abc'])
{
    $abc = $var;
    return $abc;
}

myfunction(); //returns $_SESSION['abc']
myfunction($myCustomVariable); //returns "Some Value"
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I can't use parameters just because the way that function has been built originally. It uses ton of sessions rather than any parameters but i guest i'll have to rework it. Thanks

Comment: @Olizt feel free to post the actual function, if its too large maybe pastebin it, without seeing your exact problem we can only speculate

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) which I do ***not*** recommend.

---

You could have your function accept a parameter, like this.

```
 function myfunction1($some_var)
 {
     $abc = $some_var;
     return $abc;
 }

 // call it like...
 myfunction1($myCustomVariable);
```

---

If you need to access a variable, but the name is generated by dynamic code, you can use [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

```
 function myfunction1($name_of_var)
 {
     $abc = $GLOBALS[$name_of_var];
     return $abc;
 }

 // call it like...
 $myCustomVariable = 'a value'
 myfunction1('myCustom' + 'Variable');
```

Comment: I got as far as "The direct answer is `eval`" and nearly vomited over my keyboard. Then I read "which I do not recommend". I hope @Olizt understands how strongly it is not recommended they use it.

Comment: It's the first time I've ever needed italics and bold at once.  That's what the question is really asking about though...